# Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'tasks'

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error, and found only answers to users of laravel..

I have this query:

```
  $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT branches.branch_id, branches.branch_name,
        tasks.task_name, tasks.task_status, tasks.real_amount,
        tasks.task_start, tasks.task_finish, tasks.description, projects.proj_name, projects.project_id
        FROM retail2.branches, retail2.projects, retail2.tasks
        JOIN tasks ON tasks.branch_id = branches.branch_id;
        JOIN branches_projects ON projects.project_id = branches_projects.proj_id
        JOIN branches ON branches.branch_id = branches_projects.branch_id");
```

and I've been trying to debug but I can't find out what the issue is... any suggestion please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you really trying to join tables between two databases, the current default database and the `retail2` database? Or are they the same DB?

Comment: You shouldn't mix a cross product in `FROM` with explicit `JOIN`.

Comment: is always the same database, all the time

Comment: branches and and retail2.branches are different tables (?), but you don't alias them so SQL can tell the difference. Even if they are the same table, since they are sources twice in the from and joins, so they would need to have alias assigned.

Comment: Why are you listing some tables twice? You have `branches` and `tasks` in the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: @riggsfolly I tried that but there's no change including the DB name in the JOINS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to list tables in both the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses. You just need to reorder the `JOIN` clauses, because a `JOIN` can only refer to tables in previous `JOIN` or `FROM` clauses.

You also have a `;` in the middle of the query, at the end of the `JOIN tasks` line. Everything after that is not part of the query, and this will cause an error becauase PDO doesn't allow multiple queries in one call.

```
SELECT branches.branch_id, branches.branch_name,
    tasks.task_name, tasks.task_status, tasks.real_amount,
    tasks.task_start, tasks.task_finish, tasks.description, projects.proj_name, projects.project_id
    FROM projects
    JOIN branches_projects ON projects.project_id = branches_projects.proj_id
    JOIN branches ON branches.branch_id = branches_projects.branch_id
    JOIN tasks ON tasks.branch_id = branches.branch_id;
```

Comment: thanks, it seems cleaner now. However I realize the many to may relationships, (between 'branches' and 'projects' through the table 'branches_projects' is getting me stuck, i'm trying to find out how to manage this issue because with your solution MySql throws me "column 'branches_projects' is unknown in ON clause"...

Comment: None of my ON clauses refer to a column named `branches_projects`, it's always used as the table name. I think you may have copied it wrong.